# how to retrieve the index size of a field array

Tags: entities, theming, media

What I am working with it this. I have a custom content type with an image field (field_img) that accepts multiple images so they are stored in an array. what I need to figure out how to do is one of two things and I need to do them from the node--custom.tpl.php if possible.

1: get the size of the $node->field_img array so I can then loop through and assign appropriate HTML id's for each image in the content type.

OR

2: directly loop through the field_img array using maybe foreach() to set the id of each image in the content type to an appropriately unique value.

what I am able to do here works for one value because I can put in the actual index of the instance I am working with but the arrays are not all the same length some have 10 images some have only 6 so I need something that will loop through the array.

Here is the static code that works for one element

```
<div id="gallery-img-wrapper">  

<?php $i = 0 ?>

<img class="album-image<?php print $i ?>" src="<?php print render (file_create_url($node->field_img['und'][$i]['uri'])); ?>">

</div>
```

this is inside node--gallery.tpl.php and it works fine but it only displays 1 image and I need 14 or how ever many there are for the instance of the content type.

Comment: You mention foreach(), but did you try it? Seems to me that it should work. foreach($node->field_img[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $key => $value)

Comment: I did try it but I couldn't figure out the syntax. I'll try your snippet thanks.

Comment: Ok awesome it did work. I ended up changing the [LANGUAGE_NONE] to ['und'] but it did work either way. Thanks 2pha. you should put in your answer so I can give you a rep point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention `foreach()`, but did you try it? Seems to me that it should work. `foreach($node->field_img[LANGUAGE_NONE] as $key => $value)`